# C# WinForms ListView RetrieveVirtualItem wants ItemIndex from the end of list

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView in virtual mode with 100k+ VirtualListSize. I'm getting data for it from some kind of IEnumearable. I wanted to get data for only visible indices (0..29) to speed up my app via lazy object creation. But when I log the indices it called I get the following(for 112341 items):

```
GetData 0
GetData 5
GetData 112338 // WTF IS THAT!? i've got a 20 sec delay to get this data couse it only can be obtained through getting all the previous indecis ( 
GetData 112339 // WTF IS THAT!?
GetData 112340 // WTF IS THAT!?
GetData 1
GetData 2
GetData 3
GetData 4
GetData 6
....
GetData 29
```

Thats how i fill it:

```
    private void SetDataToList(object sender, PlFastSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        listView.BeginUpdate();
        _listViewCache = new ListViewItem[e.SearchData.Count];
        _source = e.SearchData;
        listView.VirtualListSize = _listViewItems.Length;
        listView.EndUpdate();
    }
```

And the

```
    private void listView_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var anItem = _listViewCache[e.ItemIndex];
        if (anItem == null)
        {
            Debug.Print("GetData "+e.ItemIndex);
            anItem = CreateListItemFromElement(_source.GetData(e.ItemIndex));
            _listViewCache[e.ItemIndex] = anItem;
        }
        e.Item = anItem;
    }
```

Any Ideas how can I make listview calling only VISIBLE indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution so far. First, expand native ListView with that function:

```
    private const uint LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE = 0x1000 + 182;

    public bool ItemIsVisible(int itemIndex)
    {
        return (uint)NativeMethods.SendMessage(Handle, LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE, (IntPtr)itemIndex, (IntPtr)0) != 0;
    }
```

It will help us to get item visibility by index([LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Next, use that in

```
    private readonly ListViewItem _blankListItem = new ListViewItem();

    private void listView_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!listView.ItemIsVisible(e.ItemIndex))
        {
            e.Item = _blankListItem;
            return;
        }

        var anItem = _listViewItems[e.ItemIndex];
        if (anItem == null)
        {
            anItem = CreateListItemFromElement(_source.GetData(e.ItemIndex));
            _listViewItems[e.ItemIndex] = anItem;
        }
        e.Item = anItem;
    }
```

You will actually never see that blank item. 
Works pretty nice even for 120k+ items for me.